# in a bit of something

Tags: meaning

Source: [Sams Teach Yourself C++ in 24 Hours, 5th Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672333317)

> Programmers differ in the conventions they adopt for variable names. Some prefer all lowercase letters for variable names with underscores separating words, such as high_score and player_score . Others prefer lowercase letters except for the first letter of new words, such as highScore and playerScore . (**In a bit of programming lore**, the latter convention has been dubbed CamelCase because the middle-of-word capitalization looks like a camel’s hump.)

What synonymous phrase can you think of that means approximately the same thing as *in a bit of something*? Because I'm not entirely sure if I genuinely comprehend the meaning of this expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In a bit of programming lore

means basically

> The thing I am about to tell you fits in the category of programming lore.

That's probably a more wordy than it needs to be, but it is the general idea.
Other similar uses of "In a bit of X" would be things like

> In a bit of weird news, a truck carrying beer collided with a truck carrying chips today.
>
> In a bit of history trivia, William Shakespeare's skull is missing from his tomb.